# How to obtain SNR when we have the samples of a non-DC noisy signal in practice?

Tags: noise, signal-processing

This may sound a naive question but I couldn't find an example. Let me begin with what I know about SNR and where I am confused.

Lets say I have a DC like signal with some random noise on it and I have the samples. I can then by using MATLAB or any such a tool subtract the mean value from the samples and obtain the noise floor and calculate the noise rms. So I can eventually find the SNR by dividing the signal power to the noise power.

But if the signal lets say is a sine wave with random noise like below:

[image]

in this case how can we calculate the SNR if we have all the samples? To do that we need the noise samples and rms noise. But my problem here I cannot use the same method I was using for the noisy DC input case. What is the convenient way to obtain the noise and SNR for this case?

Comment: Can't you just subtract the expected sine wave from the samples? What **exactly** are you asking?

Comment: I dont know the original expected sine

Comment: If you don't know what the signal is supposed to be how can you possibly know what the noise is?

Comment: Your question currently cannot be answered because, as Elliot said above, it makes no sense to talk about the SNR if the signal is unknown. Perhaps you could re-write your question (or ask a new one) explaining what you really want to achieve, and how you plan to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1: FFT**

Since this is a sinewave, perform a FFT. The FFT peak is your signal, bin 0 is DC offset, and all other bins are noise. Sum the power of all noise bins to get total noise power, the ratio with signal power gives SNR.

The advantage of this method is you can also look at noise spectrum if you are interested in it, and it's pretty simple. It requires a periodic signal though. It can work for signals that are not pure sines, but you will need to ignore the FFT bins which correspond to harmonics of the signal, as these are not noise.

**Method 2: reconstruct original signal and substract**

If the signal isn't a sine or at least something that FFT handles well, you can reconstruct it, maybe by fitting a signal-generating function to the samples or something like that. If it is a data transmission, you could recover the data, then reconstruct the signal that was transmitted, then align it with the received samples, and substract to get the noise. This is a bit more... hazardous.

Comment: I see so the peak will be the pure sine signal power. But all the rest is the noise and I need to sum them. Is there a way to perform the sum or integration on the FFT noise? I can plot the FFT in MATLAB but didnt sum the FFT coefficients. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Beware, bin 0 is your DC offset, so that isn't noise. To sum noise power, I don't remember matlab syntax, it'll be something like: square your vector to get power, and use sum() with correct indices